# MapView location not working (ios7 in xcode 6, sdk ios8)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I installed XCODE 6 the version form developer.apple (I think is the final one) and Im working my projects there (iOS 7 projects) but obviously brings iOS 8 SDK I really don't know if this affects the project.

I have a mapview and I want to show the user location but it's impossible!
Code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *manager;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [self.manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.mapview setDelegate:self];
    self.mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;


    [self.mapview setCenterCoordinate:self.mapview.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

I don't get the "App whants to use your current location...", The mapview shows some place in Africa without pin or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must init/alloc the `CLLocationManager *manager`

something like this:

```
    // Create the core location manager object
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;


    // for iOS 8, specific user level permission is required,
    // "when-in-use" authorization grants access to the user's location
    //
    // important: be sure to include NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription along with its
    // explanation string in your Info.plist or startUpdatingLocation will not work.
    //
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

check Apple example https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801

Comment: I did not read about NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription mentioned  in comments in code part , thats why i posted a new answer. I now see it , so i have removed my answer , sorry for that.

Comment: Its very strange beacuse with this code I still get in console: Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
And even with that methods the user location does not show :(

Comment: 1) 1In the simulator you have to enable location simulation in the scheme settings or in the toolbar at the bottom of the debug window 2) Keep in mind that NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription keys are now mandatory, so you should include that in your plist